# Why GoogleApiClient is not connected in Android Wear app while using WearCompanionLibrary (WCL)?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, wear-companion-library

In my use case I try to send data (larger than 100K) from a wear companion app to the wear app. I'm leveraging WearCompanionLibrary (WCL, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary). I'm aiming for the low level Channel API, the sample app (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WclDemoSample) is somewhat reverse: it sends an image from the wear to the companion.

But I don't even get to that point, because even though I execute `WearManager.initialize(getApplicationContext());` in both the wear app's and the mobile app's `onCreate()`, when it comes to send the data the `wearManager.getConnectedNodes();` returns empty node set.

Consequently if I try to set `wearManager.removeCapabilities(CAPABILITY_FILE_PROCESSOR);` in the main activity of the wear app (which will receive the data), I get an exception from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary/blob/master/WCL/src/main/java/com/google/devrel/wcl/WearManager.java#L594

I don't understand why. Debugging into WCL it properly calls

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new MyConnectionCallbacksListener())
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new MyConnectionFailedListener())
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

under the hood: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary/blob/master/WCL/src/main/java/com/google/devrel/wcl/WearManager.java#L140

I use API 25 Wear emulator, I include 10.0.1 Play Services in the companion app part because I use `GcmTaskService`.

```
import com.google.devrel.wcl.WearManager;

public class MyWearApp extends Application {
    private static MyWearApp application;

    public MyWearApp getInstance() {
        return application;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        WearManager.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        application = this;
    }
...
}
```

Alternatively, if you have any tips on how to achieve this absolutely simple task of sending <100K binary data from one node to another, please let me know. I tried DataLayer API in several different ways (DataMap, notification), with no satisfaction.

Comment: is it possible you're calling isConnected() before the client is connected (`GoogleApiClient#connect()` is called in `WearManager#initialize()` and is a non-blocking call)?

Comment: I'll check on that. That could be the case with the `removeCapabilities` call, which I commented out now, it's not essential if I don't filter the nodes. But in my use case the app has plenty of time to connect. First I start the wear app which goes to a waiting position, then the companion which needs some UI interaction to initiate the data transfer. So there's plenty of time.

Comment: I noticed that the sample app (android-WclDemoSample) subcalsses `WearActivity`. I downgraded the wear libraries to 1.3.0 (from 1.4.0) in my apps to match WCL's version, same with the play libraries (8.4.0 instead 10.0.1). I think these versions contribute to the problem. I suspect there's a star constellation of proper version combination which is required for the functionality. We have to find the DaVinci code.

Comment: What happens if you try connecting to your own GoogleApiClient w/o the lib and register callback `registerConnectionCallbacks` and `registerConnectionFailedListener` to see what's happening (or just use `blockingConnect` and view the `ConnectionResult` returned)?

Comment: @z153 Good point, next step for debugging. When I was trying various DataLayer techniques, I issued those instruction from the realm of my app. Since I compile WCL from source, I'll actually modify that so I can see what's going on.

Comment: On the wear side the `Application`'s `onCreate` with the `WearManager.initialize(getApplicationContext());` was actually called later than the main `Activity`'s `onCreate` with the `wearManager.addCapabilities(...)`. Now I'm debugging why the companion app doesn't connect.